# Performing boolean operations on Eigen arrays

Tags: c++, eigen, c++98

I'm trying to use various boolean operations on Eigen matrices. For example, setting NaN or Inf values to a specific value. Or setting values above or below specific values to something else.

I could loop through each value and perform each boolean operation, but I imagine that there's a chance this could miss out on vectorisation, particularly on my C++98 compiler without automatic vectorisation.

I can use unaryExpr for example

```
template <int replacementValue>
static float ReplaceNanWithValue(float value)
{
    if (std::isnan(value) == true)
    {
        value = static_cast<float>(replacementValue);
    }
    return value;
}

matrix1 = matrix1 .unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(ReplaceNanWithValue<1>));
```

However, as I'm using C++98, I'm using the template argument to limit the value I'm setting the Nan with, to a value that can be represented by an int, as you can't use floats or doubles with this template argument also I'm unable to use this method with values that are determined at runtime rather than compile time. With C++11 I could use an anonymous function to do this

```
const float MaxValue = pow(n, p);
matrix1 = matrix1.unaryExpr([&MaxValue](float value) { return (value > MaxValue) ? MaxValue : value; };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to this could be to use the select function.

```
const float MaxValue = pow(n, p);
matrix1 = (matrix1.array() > MaxValue).select(MaxValue, matrix1);
```

However I'm unaware of the performance of this compared with writing a plain loop or C++11 specific solutions such as an anonymous function.

Comment: At the moment `select()` expressions are essentially equivalent to writing a plain loop. They might in the future be optimized to corresponding SIMD expressions. Your last expression can actually be written as `matrix1 = matrix1.cwiseMin(MaxValue);` (you may get slightly different behavior when there are NaNs involved).

Comment: Thanks. I was worried that the example using `select` may use more memory generating a boolean matrix, and thus incur additional overhead. The example was a somewhat contrived example that I created, because I didn't want to post the code that I'm actually working with, I will find another example that doesn't have a `cwise`/`array` implementation.

Comment: Eigen uses expression templates to remove temporaries, so in your `select` case Eigen will generate a single for loop (since coefficients in matrix1 are stored sequentially, the loops on columns/rows are fused as a single one).

Comment: Ok, that's interesting to know. If I were to use a compiler with automatic vectorisation could there be any difference between a plain loop and `select()` expressions in terms of SIMD?

Comment: If your compiler is smart enough to compile something equivalent to `for(int i...) res[i]=CONDITION ? a[i] : b[i];` to a corresponding comparison+blend operation, then it _might_ already be able to optimize this fully (the code above is hidden into several inlined functions, so it may not be obvious for the compiler).